# How to multiply numpy 2D array with numpy 1D array?

Tags: python, numpy

The two arrays:

```
a = numpy.array([[2,3,2],[5,6,1]])
b = numpy.array([3,5])
c = a * b
```

What I want is:

```
c = [[6,9,6],
     [25,30,5]]
```

But, I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2)
```

How to **multiply** a nD array with 1D array, where `len(1D-array) == len(nD array)`?

Comment: For users searching how to create a 3D array by multiplying a 2D array with a 1D array (the title of this question), note the solution is `a * b[:, None, None]` (or equivalently `numpy.multiply.outer(b, a)`), not  `a * b[:, None]` which corresponds to additional details in the question body.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to convert array b to a (2, 1) shape array, use None or `numpy.newaxis` in the index tuple:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([[2,3,2],[5,6,1]])
b = numpy.array([3,5])
c = a * b[:, None]
```

Here is the [document](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing).

Comment: Thanks! What is the name of this syntax in Python: `[:, None]`?

Comment: @Ashwin, you can search `numpy.newaxis` for it.

Comment: How does this work when `a` has an arbitrary number of dimensions?

Answer (score 3):

Another strategy is to [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the 
second array, so it has the same number of dimensions as the first array:

```
c = a * b.reshape((b.size, 1))
print(c)
# [[ 6  9  6]
#  [25 30  5]]
```

Alternatively, the [shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) attribute of the second array can be modified in-place:

```
b.shape = (b.size, 1)
print(a.shape)  # (2, 3)
print(b.shape)  # (2, 1)
print(a * b)
# [[ 6  9  6]
#  [25 30  5]]
```