# How can I broadcast between 1D and nD arrays to obtain a (1+n)D array output?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an n-dimensional ndarray `z0`, and a 1-dimensional ndarray `za`. The sizes don't correspond to each other in any way. I'd like to be able to create a new n+1-dimensional array, `z`, where `z[i]=z0+za[i]`. Is there some simple way to do this with broadcasting?

This is not equivalent to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229823/how-to-multiply-numpy-2d-array-with-numpy-1d-array). If `z0` is 2D, this can be easily achieved as follows:

```
z0[np.newaxis]+norm.ppf(alphas)[:,None]
```

However, I need to be able to do this regardless of z0's dimensionality, and so simply adding the correct number of `None` or `np.newaxis` terms won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
z = za.reshape(za.shape + (1,)*z0.ndim) + z0
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np
z0 = np.ones((2, 3, 4, 5))
za = np.ones(6)

z = za.reshape(za.shape + (1,)*z0.ndim) + z0

print z.shape
# (6, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like

```
>>> z0 = np.random.random((2,3,4))
>>> za = np.random.random(5)
>>> z = np.rollaxis((z0[...,None] + za), -1)
>>> z.shape
(5, 2, 3, 4)
>>> [np.allclose(z[i], z0 + za[i]) for i in range(len(za))]
[True, True, True, True, True]
```

where I've used `...` to mean any number of dimensions, and `rollaxis` to put it in the shape I think you want.  If you don't mind the new axis being at the end, you could get away with `z0[..., None] + za`, I think.