# Converting bsxfun with @times to numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, octave, bsxfun

This is the code I have in Octave:

```
sum(bsxfun(@times, X*Y, X), 2)
```

The bsxfun part of the code produces element-wise multiplication so I thought that `numpy.multiply(X*Y, X)` would do the trick but I got an exception. When I did a bit of research I found that element-wise multiplication won't work on Python arrays (specifically if X and Y are of type "numpy.ndarray"). So I was wondering if anyone can explain this a bit more -- i.e. would type casting to a different type of object work? The Octave code works so I know I don't have a linear algebra mistake. I'm assuming that bsxfun and numpy.multiply are not actually equivalent but I'm not sure why so any explanations would be great.

I was able to find a [website](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html)! that gives Octave to Matlab function conversions but it didn't seem to be help in my case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code translation

Comment: when you apply `sum()` in NumPy are you selecting the right `axis`?

Comment: "I'm having a lot of trouble" is not very informative. Please describe the behavior you see, a reproducible example is the best way to do that.

Comment: Is `bsxfun(@times, X*Y, X)` the same as `(X*Y).*X`?

Comment: @Eric no it's the same (in Matlab) as `(X*Y)*repmat(X, size(X,2), 1)` (assuming here the `X` is a row vector). `(X*Y).*X` will be a syntax error unless the dimensions of `(X*Y)` and of `X` are identical. Matlab does not braodcast, or expand along a singelton dimension, automatically like octave or numpy do. That's what `bsxfun` is for. I know that in some instances Octave will perform the expansion automatically in which case the answer to your question is yes

Comment: The question would be a lot clearer if we had the dimensions of `X` and `Y`, and the exact nature of the exception.

Comment: did you manage to get the equivalent code in python/numpy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`bsxfun` in Matlab stand for binary singleton expansion, in numpy it's called broadcasting and should happen automatically. The solution will depend on the dimensions of your `X`, i.e. is it a row or column vector but this answer shows one way to do it:

[How to multiply numpy 2D array with numpy 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229823/how-to-multiply-numpy-2d-array-with-numpy-1d-array)

I think that the issue here is that broadcasting requires one of the dimensions to be `1` and, unlike Matlab, numpy seems to differentiate between a 1 dimensional 2 element vector and a 2 dimensional 2 element, i.e. the difference between a matrix of shape `(2,)` and of shape `(2,1)`, you need the latter for broadcasting to happen.

Comment: Is there no bxnfun in numpy? What if I wanted to do a element wise sum for example.

Comment: You just do the sum, numpy will automatically broadcast it along a dimension. So just `+` in numpy is the same as `bsxfun(@plus,,)` in Matlab *provided* your numpy dimensions are right

Comment: so is the python code just literally just `A + B` or `A * B` (assuming A has say Dx1 and B has 1 x K).

Comment: @Pinocchio yes exactly, but make sure that in numpy you have a 2D array and not  a 1D array, i.e. a `D`-by-`1` 2D array as opposed to a `D` element 1D array. Note that in MATLAB no such distinction exists. Also from MATLAB 2016b, `A + B` will work as well, i.e. automatic broadcasting is finally coming to MATLAB too

Answer (score 3):

For those who don't know Numpy, I think it's worth pointing out that the equivalent of Octave's (and Matlab's) `*` operator (matrix multiplication) is `numpy.dot` (and, debatably, `numpy.outer`).  Numpy's `*` operator is similar to `bsxfun(@times,...)` in Octave, which is itself a generalization of `.*`.

In Octave, when applying bsxfun, there are implicit singleton dimensions to the right of the "true" size of the operands; that is, an `n1 x n2 x n3` array can be considered as `n1 x n2 x n3 x 1 x 1 x 1 x...`.  In Numpy, the implicit singleton dimensions are to the left; so an `m1 x m2 x m3` can be considered as `... x 1 x 1 x m1 x m2 x m3`.  This matters when considering operand sizes: in Octave, `bsxfun(@times,a,b)` will work if a is `2 x 3 x 4` and b is `2 x 3`. In Numpy one could not multiply two such arrays, but one *could* multiply a `2 x 3 x 4` and a `3 x 4` array.

Finally, `bsxfun(@times, X*Y, X)` in Octave will probably look something like `numpy.dot(X,Y) * X`.  There are still some gotchas: for instance, if you're expecting an outer product (that is, in Octave X is a column vector, Y a row vector), you could look at using `numpy.outer` instead, or be careful about the shape of X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

Little late, but I would like to provide an example of having equivalent `bsxfun` and `repmat` in python. This is a little bit of code I was just converting from Matlab to Python numpy:

**Matlab:**

```
x =

    -2
    -1
     0
     1
     2

n =

 2

M = repmat(x,1,n+1)

M =

    -2    -2    -2
    -1    -1    -1
     0     0     0
     1     1     1
     2     2     2


M = bsxfun(@power,M,0:n)

M =

     1    -2     4
     1    -1     1
     1     0     0
     1     1     1
     1     2     4
```

**Equivalent in Python**:

```
In [8]: x
Out[8]: 
array([[-2],
       [-1],
       [ 0],
       [ 1],
       [ 2]])

In [9]: n=2

In [11]: M = np.tile(x, (1, n + 1))

In [12]: M
Out[12]: 
array([[-2, -2, -2],
       [-1, -1, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2]])



In [13]:  M = np.apply_along_axis(pow, 1, M, range(n + 1))

In [14]: M
Out[14]: 
array([[ 1, -2,  4],
       [ 1, -1,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  2,  4]])
```